# How to run Android emulator with WebStorm for Ionic apps

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, webstorm, android-virtual-device

I am running my `Ionic` apps either on my browser currently. The problem with it is that it does not support DB connections and every time I run the app it gives be `cordova_not_available` error in the console logs.

I already have `Android SDK` and `Android IDE` installed along with `AVD manager` on my `Win 1`0 machine. However I am not sure how to integrate/setup `WebStorm` with `AVD` so that I can run my `Ionic` apps directly on it so it is easier to debug and test.

Please guide.

Comment: Did you not find this: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/08/developing-ionic-apps-in-webstorm/ ? Or are you asking for a similar feature/functionality as requested in the comments: line-by-line debugging a Ionic/Cordova app running in emulator?

Comment: Thank you so much @MorrisonChang for the pointer. That helped a lot.